# MariaDB not caching any queries

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query-cache

I tested several simple queries like such:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE courses='a';
```

But none are being cached. The following are the cache related variables:

```
show variables like "%cache%";
+-------------------------------+----------------------+
| Variable_name                 | Value                |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+
| aria_pagecache_age_threshold  | 300                  |
| aria_pagecache_buffer_size    | 100000000            |
| aria_pagecache_division_limit | 100                  |
| binlog_cache_size             | 32768                |
| binlog_stmt_cache_size        | 32768                |
| have_query_cache              | YES                  |
| join_cache_level              | 2                    |
| key_cache_age_threshold       | 300                  |
| key_cache_block_size          | 1024                 |
| key_cache_division_limit      | 100                  |
| key_cache_segments            | 0                    |
| max_binlog_cache_size         | 18000000000000000000 |
| max_binlog_stmt_cache_size    | 18000000000000000000 |
| metadata_locks_cache_size     | 1024                 |
| query_cache_limit             | 1048576              |
| query_cache_min_res_unit      | 4096                 |
| query_cache_size              | 0                    |
| query_cache_strip_comments    | OFF                  |
| query_cache_type              | ON                   |
| query_cache_wlock_invalidate  | OFF                  |
| stored_program_cache          | 256                  |
| table_definition_cache        | 400                  |
| table_open_cache              | 400                  |
| thread_cache_size             | 0                    |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+
```

The cache related status shows:

```
show status like "%cache%";
+-----------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                     | Value |
+-----------------------------------+-------+
| Aria_pagecache_blocks_not_flushed | 0     |
| Aria_pagecache_blocks_unused      | 15737 |
| Aria_pagecache_blocks_used        | 2     |
| Aria_pagecache_read_requests      | 78    |
| Aria_pagecache_reads              | 3     |
| Aria_pagecache_write_requests     | 6     |
| Aria_pagecache_writes             | 0     |
| Binlog_cache_disk_use             | 0     |
| Binlog_cache_use                  | 0     |
| Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use        | 0     |
| Binlog_stmt_cache_use             | 0     |
| Com_assign_to_keycache            | 0     |
| Qcache_free_blocks                | 0     |
| Qcache_free_memory                | 0     |
| Qcache_hits                       | 0     |
| Qcache_inserts                    | 0     |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes              | 0     |
| Qcache_not_cached                 | 0     |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache           | 0     |
| Qcache_total_blocks               | 0     |
| Ssl_callback_cache_hits           | 0     |
| Ssl_session_cache_hits            | 0     |
| Ssl_session_cache_misses          | 0     |
| Ssl_session_cache_mode            | NONE  |
| Ssl_session_cache_overflows       | 0     |
| Ssl_session_cache_size            | 0     |
| Ssl_session_cache_timeouts        | 0     |
| Ssl_used_session_cache_entries    | 0     |
| Subquery_cache_hit                | 0     |
| Subquery_cache_miss               | 0     |
| Threads_cached                    | 0     |
+-----------------------------------+-------+
```

I have read through the [manual](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/query-cache/) and checked that the following conditions are satisfied:

- the query_cache_type server variable is set to 1, or ON
- the following functions are not present in the query: BENCHMARK()
  CONNECTION_ID() CONVERT_TZ() CURDATE() CURRENT_DATE() CURRENT_TIME()
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() CURTIME() DATABASE() ENCRYPT() (one parameter)
  FOUND_ROWS() GET_LOCK() LAST_INSERT_ID() LOAD_FILE()
  MASTER_POS_WAIT() NOW() RAND() RELEASE_LOCK() SLEEP() SYSDATE()
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP() (no parameters) USER() UUID() UUID_SHORT()
- it is not of the form:

  SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...
     SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE ...
     SELECT ... INTO DUMPFILE ...
     SELECT ... FOR UPDATE
     SELECT * FROM ... WHERE autoincrement_column IS NULL
     SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE
- it uses a non-TEMPORARY table
- it does not generate a warning
- it does not access a partitioned table
- it does not access a table from INFORMATION_SCHEMA, mysql or the
  performance_schema database
- it does not make use of user or local variables
- it does not make use of stored functions
- it does not make use of user-defined functions
- it is not inside a transaction with the SERIALIZABLE isolation level

The only thing I am not sure is:

- the user does not have a column-level privilege on any table in the
  query

I run `SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM Users;` and all columns contain "select, insert, update". Even newly created tables contain those privileges. Can anyone explain what could be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed one thing.

```
query_cache_size              | 0
```

> To set the size of the query cache, set the `query_cache_size` system variable. Setting it to 0 disables the query cache, as does setting `query_cache_type`=0.
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-cache-configuration.html
>
> Although enabled, the query cache size is by default 0KB, which effectively disables the query cache. Enable it by setting to an amount > 40KB
>
> https://mariadb.com/kb/en/query-cache/

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_query_cache_size

Comment: You are correct. I vaguely remembered I saw a default of 8M when I was looking through the variable, which turns out to be wrong. Thanks!